# tag <video> controlando por javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Como faço para que, quando clicar no vídeo ele começar a carregar, pois não estou conseguindo se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Aqui está o trecho de código do vídeo:

```
<div class="video">
   <video class="video" loop controls tabindex="0">
      <source src="video/nome_do_video.mp4"/>
   </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O nome do método é play(), no entanto, deve acessá-lo pela árvore DOM pois não é um método do JQuery e sim, do DOM Object.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $('video.video').click(function() {
        $(this).get(0).paused ? $(this).get(0).play() : $(this).get(0).pause();
    });
});
```

Nesse script, caso o video esteja pausado, será acionado a ação de `play()`, caso contrário, será pausado.

Comment: obrigado cara me ajudou muito

Comment: cara só uma pergunta como que eu faco pra tipo ter um buffer pra ele inicia só depois que o vídeo carregar pelo menos 15% ?

Comment: no google, busque assim "html5 video buffer before playing"

Comment: muito obrigado.